# Can I use bootstrap-sass with ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-sass, ngx-bootstrap

I have to implement a front-end that is currently just cutups from a third party, and I am using Angular 4 and angular-cli. I would rather use angular-material, but a lot of the html and css is done, and it's not my job as a UI dev to redo UX, so.... My question is, since I am using sass for styles, can I use the following?

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap-sass
```

and then point my styles to

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.scss",
   "styles.scss",
],...
```

???

Comment: **YES** as ngx-bootstrap does not include styles. Keep in mind that bootstrap-sass is a little out of date, but I've been using it on my projects without an conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Many people use both, however, it is not recommended because of the bloat it would put on the bundle, and also, it might not create a unified look and feel, which is what a style library primarily aims to address.